# writing matrix with hat in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, accents, semantics

I want to know the difference between:

```
$\hat{\mathbf{M}}$  % hat is not bold
and
$\mathbf{\hat{M}}$ % hat is bold
```

What is correct way (bold/normal). If both what are cases when I should use bold and when normal hat.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the hat to be bold or not. However the first should be `$\hat{\mathbf{M}}$`

Comment: @Mico, I wanted to know when should I use bold hat and when normal hat.

Comment: Whether or not the hat symbol is supposed to be bold as well really depends on what `M`, `\hat{M}`, `\mathbf{M}`, and thus also `\hat{\mathbf{M}}` and `\mathbf{\hat{M}}` are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the meaning of what you want to write. This is a matter of pure semantics. You have two options:

1. If the « hat » means « matrix M », then the hat is not part of the name of the matrix. It just says that M is a matrix. In this case, you should use `\hat{\mathbf{M}}`.
2. However, if you call the matrix « M̂ », that is, the « hat » is actually a part of the name, then you should use `\mathbf{\hat{M}}`.

To sum up: if the « hat » is part of the name, make it bold, else make it normal.